# Multiset: notation for size and number of unique items

Tags: multisets

Given a multiset, e. g. `S = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5}`, what would be a short, concise notation to express the number of unique items in the multiset? (five in the given example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *set* of unique items in multiset $S$ is usually called the *support* of $S$, and denoted $\operatorname{supp}S$. So, you can combine this with your preferred notation for number of elements: $\#$ or $|\cdot|$ to form 
$$\# (\operatorname{supp}S) \qquad \text{or}\qquad |\operatorname{supp}S|$$
Both are reasonably concise and are pretty descriptive.

According to [OEIS Wiki](http://oeis.org/wiki/Multisets), the cardinality of support of a multiset is called its *dimension*. Following this terminology, one could use $\dim S$. However, I don't find this as intuitive as either of the above options. And the usage of the term *dimension* may be somewhat narrow.

Comment: In Cybernetics (which is not mathematics) the magnitude of the support of a multiset is called its "variety". I would agree that dimension is not a good name, but "magnitude of the support of a multiset" sounds rather clunky. Variety seems better because it reduces to the size of a set when no elements are repeated.